# Block quote left border same height as text

Tags: css, blockquote

How can I make a block quote line the exact same height as the text that's inside the element.

Here is an example of what It should look like:

[image]

This is the current result that I'm getting from the code that I have created:

```css
blockquote {
  margin: 20px 0 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left: 5px solid #1371b8;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>Test</blockquote>
```

From the result, we can see that the line Is vertically bigger than the text.

Comment: This would be highly dependent on the font being used. Characters are **supposed** to have space above and below them for readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NOTE: inline-flex doesn't support older browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox 
 But it does work...

- Added a span inside the blockquote to position it optimally; keep in mind you'll have to redo this when you change fonts or font-size!

```css
blockquote {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-left: 5px solid #66e4b4;
  display:inline-flex;
} 

blockquote span {
  margin-top:-10px;
  margin-bottom:-10px;
}
```

```html
  <blockquote ><span>windows to the universe</span></blockquote>
```

– This answer is based on the original code snippet (found below) by [عارف بن الأزرق](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4213780/%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%81-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%B2%D8%B1%D9%82)

Comment: it's bad to take someone code then make a new answer

Comment: My apologies, it is indeed based on your code. I will edit my answer to show this, and won't forget to reference in the future. 

As comments are meant for _clarification/to point out problems_ I felt it wouldn't suffice, as the questions would benefit more from a new code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution of blockquote line height issue.
Just make the blockquote:before and add the border left and adjust with position absolute. you have done. :)

```css
blockquote{    
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 52px;
    margin: 28px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 0 26px;    
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #CC6B39;    
    position: relative;
}
blockquote:before {
    content: "";
    border-left: 6px solid #39348F;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14px;
    top: 13px;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>“Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy 
text ever since the 1500,”</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use line-height. Something like this:

```
<style> 
.header blockquote {
margin: 20px 0 30px;
padding-left: 20px;
border-left: 5px solid #1371b8;
line-height: 25px;
}
</style>

<div class="header">
<blockquote><h1>WINDOWS TO <br />
THE UNIVERSE</h1></blockquote>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try that

```css
blockquote {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-left: 5px solid #66e4b4;
}
```

```html
  <blockquote >windows to the universe</blockquote>
```

Comment: These still seem to out be out by a little? It's due to the tags height but I don't know how to make the tag the exact same height as the text.